# Can we merge [story-identification] and [book-identification]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[story-identification](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) is our main tag for locating stories. However, [book-identification](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-identification) has been recently created and has two questions in it. Can we delete or otherwise merge the second tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done, merged & synonymized.

Comment: Not every book identification question is a story identification question. [One of the book identification questions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6755/2191) was about a work of **literary theory**. **story-identification** makes absolutely no sense there.

Answer (score -1):

I think the tag [story-identification](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) has been used too enthusiastically, since several questions are not about stories:

- [Anthology of literary theory that illustrates each theory by applying it to the same works](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6755/2191) is definitely not about story identification; the central concern is literary theory.
- [Looking for a book (possibly a pair of them) with whimsical illustrations of misheard phrases](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6728/2191) isn't about stories either; the interest is more "linguistic".
- [Complete, single book of Peanuts comics?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5541/2191): Peanuts comics may be story, but a *collection* is not a story.
- [Which Biography of Einstein](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5226/2191): one may consider biographies as stories, but the question is "which biography?", i.e. which book. We already know what the story in question is, namely Einstein's biography.

So I would support a separate [book-identification](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-identification) tag which would be applied to (at least) the above question. The tag wiki excerpts should make the difference between the tags more explicit.

**Update**: merging both tags into a new tag named **identification** would be a bad choice, since [identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identification_(literature)) is a term with a different meaning: the "psychological relationship between the reader of a novel and a character in the book".

Comment: I wouldn't mind a general "identification" tag, then. But I don't think differentiating the two tags really gains anything--the purpose is one: to identify something the user can't fully remember. Anyone searching through the tags will likely care about all "types" simultaneously. In addition, the Sci-Fi/Fantasy SE, which is the only SE to really implement ID questions successfully, has a single main tag (and includes additional tags to specify medium).

Comment: An "identification" tag would be an unfortunate choice, because that is already a technical term in literature with a totally different meaning. I have added this as an update to my answer.

Comment: @Kitkat Anecdotally, I actually think that among all sites with ID questions, SciFi.SE is the one where separating the tag into multiple different ones might make the most sense. While there's not really much of a difference on Literature.SE, a site that deals with a variety of media in contrast sure has many users who *only* care about books, or films, or comics,..., not to speak of the inherent difference in the actual questions those media by their nature generate.

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach So you think that [tag:story-identification] is an appropriate tag for each of the examples I listed in my answer? I.e. for questions that aren't about finding a specific story?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe I wasn't really talking about this answer, sorry.

Comment: But no, not `story-identification`, that would be a really odd name. But I indeed don't see much of a point in separating non-fiction works from fictional works (provided they're both on-topic to begin with) by tag if at the end of the day you're always looking for a book.

Comment: @Kitkat "*Sci-Fi/Fantasy SE, which is the only SE to really implement ID questions successfully*" - [no](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*-identification) [it's](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*-identification) [not](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification). [What](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) a strange idea!

Comment: Christophe, perhaps an action that everyone could agree on might be to rename the story-ID tag to book-ID?

Comment: @Randal'Thor The problem with that idea is that some identification questions are about poems, and poems usually aren't books.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe How about "literature-identification"? I would hope everything that comes to this site could fall under that.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Fair, i stand corrected ;)

Comment: @Kitkat If you must have a single tag instead of splitting them up, I would suggest `work-identification`. `literature-identifcation` runs the risk that someone will come along and shorten it to `identification`, because the entire site is about literature, so the first part of the tag will look redundant.